# I am trying to install a new library, but get errors with patch installation

Tags: python, anaconda, patch

Following instruction on this website: https://pysptools.sourceforge.io/installation.html
I get the following errors in the anaconda prompt window:

```
(spectral_environment) PS PATH\miniconda3\envs\spectral_environment\Lib\site-packages\lightgbm> patch -b < lightgbm_2.1.2_sklearn.patch
At line:1 char:10
+ patch -b < lightgbm_2.1.2_sklearn.patch
+          ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

so i tried this

```
(spectral_environment) PS PATH\miniconda3\envs\spectral_environment\Lib\site-packages\lightgbm> patch -b lightgbm_2.1.2_sklearn.patch

patch : The term 'patch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ patch -b lightgbm_2.1.2_sklearn.patch
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (patch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

And got a different error. This is probably really obvious, but ive no idea. Could the PySp tools documentation be out of date with my version of anaconda? Has anaconda changed that much?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Those docs say "These patches are needed only if you use the ‘ml’ module. Otherwise, skip this step." Do you use that module?

Comment: I am planning to, yes. That is why I am trying to install the patches

Comment: Well, you don't have the [Patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) utility on your Windows machine by default. You'd have to get a copy. However, a library that requires patching other libraries sounds iffy at best...

Comment: Looks like you're running `patch` in PowerShell but you don't have the `patch` program installed. _Maybe_ you can get it by installing [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Thomas Well, that is not a road that i want to go down just to try this library, but it is good to know there may be a solution if I get desperate. Thanks

Comment: @AKX Okay, thanks for identifying the problem! It did seem weird to me, but I havent used a ton of libraries so wasnt sure how normal it was.